# Python Dates Hashtable

Tags: python, datetime, hashtable

I am trying to make a hash table to speed up the process of finding  the difference between a particular date to a holiday date (I have a list of 10 holiday dates).

```
holidays =['2014-01-01', '2014-01-20', '2014-02-17', '2014-05-26',
        '2014-07-04', '2014-09-01', '2014-10-13', '2013-11-11',
        '2013-11-28', '2013-12-25'] 

from datetime import datetime

holidaydate=[]

for i in range(10):
    holidaydate.append(datetime.strptime(holidays[i], '%Y-%m-%d'))


newdate=pd.to_datetime(df.YEAR*10000+df.MONTH*100+df.DAY_OF_MONTH,format='%Y-%m-%d')
#newdate contains all the 0.5 million of dates!
```

Now I want to use a hash table to calculate the difference between each of the 0.5 million dates in "newdate" to the closest holiday. I do NOT want to do the same calculation millions of times, thats why I want to use a hashtable for this.

I tried searching for a solution on google but only found stuff such as:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]
hash = {k:v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
```

And this does not work in my case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't follow what you need.  First, I don't see where you've set up a hash table, or even researched hash tables.  Second, where would you do millions of repeated calculations?  I see a table with half a million different calculations.  Since you could solve this with a relatively simple function, memoized if you want to avoid repeating some tests, I'm not sure what you need for your ultimate functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the table first. Like this.

```
import datetime

holidays =['2014-01-01', '2014-01-20', '2014-02-17', '2014-05-26',
        '2014-07-04', '2014-09-01', '2014-10-13', '2013-11-11',
        '2013-11-28', '2013-12-25'] 

hdates = []


def return_date(txt):
    _t = txt.split("-")
    return datetime.date(int(_t[0]), int(_t[1]), int(_t[2]))

def find_closest(d):
    _d = min(hdates, key=lambda x:abs(x-d))
    _diff = abs(_d - d).days
    return _d, _diff

# Convert holidays to datetime.date    
for h in holidays:
    hdates.append(return_date(h))

# Build the "hash" table
hash_table = {}

i_date = datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)

while i_date < datetime.date(2016,1,1):
    cd, cdiff = find_closest(i_date)
    hash_table[i_date] = {"date": cd, "difference": cdiff}
    i_date = i_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print hash_table[datetime.date(2014,10,15)]
```

This works on datetime.date objects instead of raw strings. It has a built-in function to convert a "yyyy-mm-dd" string to datetime.date though.

This creates a hash table for all dates between 1/1/2013 and 31/12/2015 and then tests this with just one date. You would then loop your 0.5 million dates and match the result in this dictionary (key is datetime.date object but you can of course convert this back to string if you so desire).

Anyway, this should give you the idea how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! What i wanted to do was to avoid looping though the 0.5 million data using the same difference function to calculate. Since there are only 365 different days in a year, so I actually only need to run the function 365 times instead of 0.5 million times right?

Comment: If you want to test 0,5 million rows of data, you will have to loop 0.5 million times. There is no way around that. But if you have say 10 holidays, you would in the brute force method need to do 0.5million * 10 (compare every date to every holiday).  The table will help you to reduce this to 0.5m * 1 + N*10, where N is the difference in days between the first and last dates in your data set.  It will improve performance.

Comment: Well ok thanks, but this guy used a lookup table in R to do the calculation only 365 times using unique month/day combinations in the dataset! Here is the link: https://jessesw.com/Air-Delays/

Comment: Yes, he ran 365 times the generation of the hash table. If you look at his solution, he does exactly what I am doing now. Instead of comparing every 5.9 million rows to every holiday (in his case), he only compares every holiday to 365 days.  His way of expressing himself is not the clearest possible ("We COULD run this function on every one of our 5.9 million rows"), but he clearly mentions "function", and in this case the "function" is the one that finds the holiday that is closest to the day in question.

Comment: There is no magic hash table that would allow you to compare 500000 lines to something with only 365 comparisons.  Even if your 500000 rows were as simple as true or false and you would need to analyse your data, you would need to loop through it to calculate trues and falses.

Comment: But what he succeeds to do is to do the same as I do here: instead of comparing 5.9 million rows to N items in the holiday table, he only compares every row to one item in the hash table, thus reducing looping a lot.

Comment: #newdate contains 0.5 million dates in the format 
#Out[95]:
#0        2017-01-18
#1        2017-01-18
#2        2017-01-18
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
for i in range(len(newdate)):
    a=str(newdate[i])
    b=int(a[0:4])
    c=int(a[5:7])
    d=int(a[8:10])
    
    date = datetime(year=int(a[0:4]), month=int(a[5:7]), day=int(a[8:10]))
    
    hash_table[date]

Comment: I cant seem to match the values from the dictionary, I've tried a lot of stuff

Comment: Make sure you are creating datetime.date objects instead of datetime objects.  And if your source data is formatted yyyy-mm-dd, you probably should create your dictionary with a string key in that format. This would reduce the need of datetime conversions as you do not need to convert 0,5 million strings to datetimes but match strings instead. This would also be easier to debug if it does not work. Just a thought.